# Is there any 2D renderer library with complete fixed point support for embedded linux?

Tags: linux, graphics, embedded, embedded-linux

I am working on embedded linux, Is there any open source 2D renderer available which can draw on memory, scanline based, complete fixed-point support.

I work in c or cpp programming language.

I know one with which satisfy my all needs that is, Google Skia which google uses in android and chrome, But I found it without documentation, not straight-forward compilable, not  straight-forward usable in 3rd party projects.

Regards, Sunny.

Comment: Do you have a CPU planed for this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/). I am not sure what you mean by "complete fixed-point support" but other than that it seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: kdubb, complete fixed point support means no floating point operations, all floating point operations replaced with integer operations with limited accuracy.

Comment: glad to give you first UP. :-) Welcome to SO.

Comment: Although the public API uses double, internally cairo is 24.8 fixed point since version 1.5.12.

Answer (score 1):

[Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/) is a games library which includes extensive software rendering, most of which does not rely on floating point. Additionally it has some trig functions and maths functions which work on fixed-point. It has things like sprite-rotation which don't need floating point.

Comment: Thanks, May I have there any reference or tutorial to learn it, which you found helpful?

Comment: It's all linked from the above site. You're going to be more or less on your own compiling for an embedded platform though; the community is pretty helpful however.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's what you're looking for, but there's libcrtxy
http://libcrtxy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/index.php?path=Platform%2FDirectFB).

If you want hardware acceleration , directFB is the most portable way to go.

Comment: But does it uses Fixed Point ?